# Does onCompleted works with useMutation?

Tags: react-apollo-hooks

I am using useMutation hook in react project. The mutation runs successfully but it's not reaching onCompleted afterwards.

I have set notifyOnNetworkStatusChange to true in the mutation but that doesn't seem to help.

```
const [createUser] = useMutation(SIGNUP_MUTATION);

createUser({
  variables: {
     firstname,
     lastname,
     email
  },
  notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  onCompleted: (data) => {
     // not called
     confirm(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looking at the api of [useMutation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations/#usemutation-api-overview) it seems like you're using `onCompleted` in the wrong place. it should be part of the `useMutation` definition.

```
  const [createUser] = useMutation(
    SIGNUP_MUTATION,
    {
      onCompleted(data) {
        confirm(data);
      }
    }
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          createUser({ variables: { firstname, lastname, email } }); // assuming `firstname`, `lastname` and `email` are defined somewhere.
        }}
      >
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Signup</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

A couple years later -- we can now to do this:

```
const [saveFormData] = useMutation(SAVE_FORM_DATA_MUTATION);

saveFormData({
    variables: {
        myVariable: 'test variable'
    },
    update: (cache, data) => {
        //do updates here
    }
})
```